# On the inequality from the Cassels-Frohlich book

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that $K \subseteq L$ is a finite extension of fraction fields of two DVR (say, $R \subseteq S$) with maximal ideals $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak P$ respectively. Let $e$ be the corresponding ramification index and $v_k, v_L$ the corresponding valuations.

Let me recall that we say that this extension is tamely ramified if the characteristic of the residue field does not divide $e$.

It is well-known that this condition is equivalent to the fact that $\operatorname{tr}_{L/K}(S) = R$. In their "Algebraic number theory" book (Ch. 1, Th. 5.2) Cassels and Frohlich claim that this is equivalent to $v_L(\mathcal D) = e-1$, where $\mathcal D$ is the different ideal.

Their argument contains the following fragment: they say that (now without any assumptions on $L/K$ such as the tame ramification) $(tr_{L/K}S)^{-1} = \mathcal D^{-1} \cap K$ implies $v/e < r+1$. (Here $r = v_K(tr_{K/L}S)$ and $v = v_L(\mathcal D)$).

My question is: *HOW* does this implication work?

Answer (score 1):

First, for $z \in K$, $z \in (\mathrm{tr}_{L/K}\,S)^{-1}$ iff $z\mathrm{tr}_{L/K}(S) \subset R$ iff $\mathrm{tr}_{L/K}(zS) \subset R$ iff $z \in \mathcal{D}^{-1}$, hence the equality of ideals.

Let $p,q$ be uniformizers for $R,S$ respectively, $p=q^eu$ where $u$ is a unit of $L$. We know that $\mathrm{tr}_{L/K}(S)=(p)^r$, $\mathcal{D}=(q)^v$, thus $\mathcal{D}^{-1} \cap K=\{x \in K,\, v_L(x) \geq -v\}=\{x \in K,\, v_K(x) \geq -v/e\}$, while $(\mathrm{tr}_{L/K}S)^{-1}=\{x \in K,\, v_K(x) \geq -r\}$. Thus, any integer must be at least $-r$ iff it is at least $-v/e$. In particular, $-v/e \leq -r$ (as $-r$ is at least $r$) but $-v/e> -r-1$ (as $-r-1 < r$), and the conclusion follows.